# SQL: How do I query based on a dynamic date calculation?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, `foos` that has a `last_checked_at` datetime field and a `checking_inverval` integer field.

I want to query all `foos` that haven't been checked since the checking interval. I've tried variations on the following:

```
SELECT `foos`.* FROM `foos`
  WHERE (`foos.checking_interval` < TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `foos.last_checked_at`, NOW())
```

But I have yet to have any success. Or maybe I'm barking down the wrong tree altogether, and should just have another column that has the calculated datetime and let my application handle setting that date.

Thanks

Comment: What is it returning, an error or simply 0 results? And are you sure that with your current data this query should return anything?

Comment: I get an error. I think I'm just constructing it wrong...

Comment: check this query `SELECT fooId, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, last_checked_at, UTC_TIMESTAMP()) Test, checking_interval, last_checked_at   FROM foos  WHERE checking_interval < TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, last_checked_at, UTC_TIMESTAMP())` you may be able to differenciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, where the last checked at is earlier than now minus the interval?

```
FOOS foos.*
FROM foos
WHERE foos.last_checked_at < date_sub(now(),INTERVAL foos.checking_interval SECOND)
```